# Label/Inputs positioned differently in Firefox than Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I'm trying to build a "mad libs" style template, but I have come across an issue where relatively positioned inputs wrapped in labels display unexpectedly in Firefox, but appear as expected in Safari/Chrome. I have tried researching what could be causing this, but I cannot seem to figure out what the difference between the two browsers is that is causing this incompatibility.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GhLA/1/) so you can better understand what I am describing.  Any clues on how to correct this?  Maybe I need to rewrite my HTML?  Ideally this is just a CSS issue, as this HTML is being rendered dynamically and I'd rather not have to change the back-end if possible.

And here is the HTML/CSS from the Fiddle:

HTML

```
<div class="feature" id="madlib">
  <h1>Test Test</h1>
  <div class="padded rounded border">
    <p>Dear <label>mom <input name="madlib_mom" type="text" /></label>,</p>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum <label>adjective <input name="madlib_adjective" type="text" /></label>   lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <label>thank you <input name="madlib_thank_you" type="text" /></label> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <label>noun 1 <input name="madlib_noun_1" type="text"
    </label> and <label>noun 2 <input name="madlib_noun_2" type="text" /></label> lorem ipsum lorem ipsummmm lorem, lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <label>place <input name="madlib_place" type="text" /></label>, lorem ipsum <label>favorite food <input name="madlib_favorite_food" type="text" /></label> lorem ipsum lorem <label>good advice <input name="madlib_good_advice" type="text" /></label>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"] {
  display:block;  
  position:relative;  
  top:-30px;  
  border-bottom:1px solid pink;
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
  border-top:0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;  
  position:relative;
  top:30px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
  padding:2px;
  text-align: center; 
  font-size:10px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:  To be more explicit, the labels are supposed to act as "mad libs" labels, such that they appear below the text input.  They are in the right place, roughly, in all browsers, but appear to be pushed down almost twice the distance as they are in Chrome, which causes them to overlap with the subsequent line of text.

Comment: Where are the labels positioned?  Where do you want them?

Comment: Updated with some more info.

Comment: they look the same to me in Firefox and Chrome, same position, however you may consider gettign red of the yellow outline in chrome, add this line to the css `outline: none;`

Comment: I don't see a yellow outline in my version of Chrome, and I'm all up to date.  Interesting...

Comment: Chrome version **26.0.1410** screenshot >> http://mi-creativity.com/test/images/outline_test.jpg

Comment: Weird!  I'll add that CSS, but I don't understand why I am unable to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on a discrepancy between how the browsers decide where the baseline of the `label` inline-block is. To avoid the problem use a vertical-align for the label other than the default `baseline`. For example, use `vertical-align:top` as per this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GhLA/2/

(It's very hard to tell whether Chrome or Firefox is correct with respect to the CSS specs here. It depends on whether the `display:block` of the `input` element establishes a line box inside the inline-block of the `label` element or not.)

Comment: Weird!  I had read about that but was unable to reproduce a solution that worked properly.  Glad to see it was something as simple as this.  Thanks!

Comment: IE9 shows a similar issue to FF (of course slightly different). This fixes it on it as well.